# How to copy visual studio themes and extensions to offline device

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I've done a successful offline installation of visual studio 2019 on my offline computer which can't be connected to the internet. On my laptop I installed some nice theme extensions for visual studio and i want to copy them to my offline computer. I tried copying `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions` from my laptop to my offline copmuter but that doesn't seem to do anything and also is 1.3GB, which is way more space than just a few themes.

So how can I copy those extensions to my offline computer (if I even can)?

Comment: Hi, just want to confirm your issue was solved or not, if not, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the offline package from [visual studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), then re-install it on offline computer.

If we copy installation files, some unexpected problems may make visual studio crashed.

Comment: does "download the offline package" mean clicking on the big green "download button"? it does download a pretty small .vsix file. does the file contain everything needed for the extension or does it contain some web link where the actual download happens? I tried finding some offline package download button on the page but didn't succeed

Answer (score 0):

We can try to install the extension on a machine with network connection and check the required certificate (take GitHub Extension for example), export the required certificate and open "manager user certificates" on the offline computer to export it, after that and retry this extension installation.
[image]